# JQuery sorts only if breakpoint in Firebug exists

Tags: jquery, firebug

I've created script, which sends AJAX-request and refreshes *select* element with a list of *option* elements. After it was done, I try to sort *options* elements using [JQuery plugin jQuery.sortElements.js](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/):

```
/* If region is specified */
    if (regionId != '0') {
        /* AJAX request to get city list and refresh select state. */
        $.getJSON('/json/cities', {region_id: regionId}, function(json) {
            $("select.changedBy-" + regionSelectId).each(function() {
                var citySelect = $(this);
                $.each(json, function(id, name) {
                    $('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>').appendTo(citySelect);
                });
            });
        });

        /* Sorting */
        $("select.changedBy-" + regionSelectId).each(function() {
            $(this).find('option').sortElements(function(option1, option2) {
                var option1Value = $(option1).attr('value');
                var option2Value = $(option2).attr('value');
                if (option1Value == '0') return -1;
                if (option2Value == '0') return 1;
                if (option1Value == regionId) return -1;
                if (option2Value == regionId) return 1;
                return $(option1).text() > $(option2).text() ? 1 : -1;
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, sorting works only if I put breakpoint in Firebug at the following line:

```
$("select.changedBy-" + regionSelectId).each(function() {
```

In other case (regular mode) it doesn't sort *option* elements. Could you please help me to find the cause of this issue?

Thanks,
  Boris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds and looks like a timing issue. You do realize that the `getJSON()` call is asynchronous, right? The JavaScript engine will get to `$.getJSON()`, make the request and then almost immediately get to your sorting code. It will fail to sort since there won't be any elements to sort, yet, since the request hasn't completed.

I suspect that **when you put a breakpoint, that provides enough time for the request to complete** and you see things work the way you expect them to.

I would suggest one of the following

1. Moving all of your sorting code inside the `getJSON()` callback function, right after you append all the new `<option>`s
2. Wrapping the sorting code in a function and invoking that function after you finish creating all the new `<option>`s

---

Here's code for the first suggestion (infinitesimally easier - it involved just cutting and pasting your sorting code into the callback function body):

```
 if (regionId != '0') {
        /* AJAX request to get city list and refresh select state. */
        $.getJSON('/json/cities', {region_id: regionId}, function(json) {
            $("select.changedBy-" + regionSelectId).each(function() {
                var citySelect = $(this);
                $.each(json, function(id, name) {
                    $('<option value="' + id + '">' + name + '</option>').appendTo(citySelect);
                });
            });

            /* Sorting */            
             $("select.changedBy-" + regionSelectId).each(function() {
                $(this).find('option').sortElements(function(option1, option2) {
                    var option1Value = $(option1).attr('value');
                    var option2Value = $(option2).attr('value');
                    if (option1Value == '0') return -1;
                    if (option2Value == '0') return 1;
                    if (option1Value == regionId) return -1;
                    if (option2Value == regionId) return 1;
                    return $(option1).text() > $(option2).text() ? 1 : -1;
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

javaScript is single threaded language, your sorting code is being got called when there is no option element has been created yet, since they are getting created on completion of ajax request. To force the sorting code is to be called after option element creation is to put the sorting code in a function and call it on ajax request completion, after option element created, it would be like:

```
 makeAjaxCall(callBack(){
  createOptionElements();
  SortOptionElements();
});
```

Hope it would work for you. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax request may be asynchronous. Use synchronous  Ajax request